# jquery onhover image change with active inactive function

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am having 5 images the action I need is on hover and on click colour changes for that particular image and rest will be same like inactive,if I click new image,the new image colour should change and rest will be inactive mode(previous colour),image demo is given in the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otx1B.png) I don't have any idea how to do this,please give me step by step process.

please help me out,,
Thanks in advance..

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: <img id="mynews" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/newss.png" width="182" height="86">
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('mynews');
    if (image.src.match("http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/news-hovers.png")) {
        image.src = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/newss.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/news-hovers.png";
    }
}
</script>

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for your code. that will help more

Comment: The example image you have given looks like a Sprite image, meaning, you would adjust what is viewed versus loading unique images. Is that correct?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uznj5y4r/5/ can anyone  tell why on click colour change function is not  working?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Below code will be executed when you hover or click on image
    $('img').on('hover click', function(e) {
        // Remove active Class From All Image
        $('img').removeClass("active");
        // Add Active Class To Image on which you hover or click
        $(this).addClass("active")
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

More than one way to do this. I provide a CSS example, and a JQuery example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vg3usoff/1/

**HTML**

```
<p>
  Example One:
</p>
<div id="myNews-wrapper">
</div>
<p>
  Example Two:
</p>
<img id="myNews-2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otx1B.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
div#myNews-wrapper {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otx1B.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

div#myNews-wrapper:hover {
  background-position: -73px 0px;
}

div#myNews-wrapper:active {
  background-position: -146px 0px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
function makeSprite(img, w, h) {
  if (img === '' || typeof img === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }
  var wrapId = img.attr('id') + "-wrapper";
  var wrap = $("<div>", {
    'id': wrapId
  });
  wrap.css({
    'width': w,
    'height': h,
    'overflow': "hidden",
    'background-image': "url('" + img.attr("src") + "')",
    'background-repeat': "no-repeat",
    'background-position': "0px 0px"
  });
  img.hide();
  img.after(wrap);
  return wrap;
}

$(function() {
  var myDiv = makeSprite($("#myNews-2"), 72, 72);
  myDiv.hover(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-position", e.type === "mouseenter" ? "-73px 0px" : "0px 0px");
  });
  myDiv.click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-position", "-146px 0px");
  });
});
```

I don't know how deep down the rabbit hole you want to go with this one. I wrote a Tutorial on this that might help: http://64.78.10.120/html/button_sprite.html CSS is faster and easier to work with for Sprites in my opinion. But depending on the level of control, you may want to use JQuery to handle more events or actions.

Part of your comment suggested you were using WordPress, and this is why the JQuery example is as complex as I made it. If you have existing WP Posts that have images already in them, and you're adding to it, you may not be able to swap out the `img` tags into `div` tags to make the the CSS work easily.

Let me know if this makes sense.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, I created this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uznj5y4r/6/

```
<a href="#tab1">
  <img id="mynews" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/newss.png" width="182" height="86" />
</a>

<a href="#tab2" style="font-family:rockwell;font-weight: 400;font-size: 16px;">
  <img id="myevent" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/events.png" width="182" height="86">
</a>

<a href="#tab3">
  <img id="mytwit" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/twitters.png" width="182" height="86" />
</a>
<script>
function changeImage(elem) {
    var image = elem.src;
    var img0 = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/newss.png";
    var img0Hover = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/news-hovers.png";
    var img1 = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/events.png";
    var img1Hover = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/eventshovers.png";
    var img2 = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/twitters.png";
    var img2Hover = "http://www.newshoresschoolbangalore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/twitter-hovers.png";

    switch (image) {
      case img0:
        document.getElementById('mynews').src = img0Hover;
        document.getElementById('myevent').src = img1;
        document.getElementById('mytwit').src = img2;
        break;
      case img1:
        document.getElementById('mynews').src = img0;
        document.getElementById('myevent').src = img1Hover;
        document.getElementById('mytwit').src = img2;
        break;
      case img2:
        document.getElementById('mynews').src = img0;
        document.getElementById('myevent').src = img1;
        document.getElementById('mytwit').src = img2Hover;
        break;
      default:
        document.getElementById('mynews').src = img0;
        document.getElementById('myevent').src = img1;
        document.getElementById('mytwit').src = img2;
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Twisty for your help ,,i have already done sprite animation,what i need id is  ,I have given jsfidle link of 3 images of two colours ,i want something like 1> onhover the black colour news image to be change in pink and rest will be in black colour,2>onclick it should remain in same colour(pink) rest will be black,like this i want for this 3 images,  https://jsfiddle.net/uznj5y4r/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uznj5y4r/3/ check this one,when I click first image its colour changes to pink,but when I click  second image the colour changes to pink,but in same time  the first image and other remaining images colour should be in black colour,I guess this is concept of Jquery active inactive function,I guess this can be done ,,please help me out,I guess this time everyone got my question what I need.Thank you everyone..

Comment: The way you have this written, you would have to revert all the other changes to all the other images first, and then change the image you clicked. If it's just for these 3 images, that's fine, but if you plan to do it for more, you should conform to a specific naming pattern or method.

Comment: @raazstret I updated my answer, working example forked from your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uznj5y4r/6/

Comment: @raazstret Another example using JQuery and leveraging `.data()` features. This would be more dynamic and could work for a larger number of tabs or buttons. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uznj5y4r/8/

Comment: @raazstret I am glad to hear it. If the this answer helps, I hope you will upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: hi Twisty will you please help me here, when I hover image both image and text moving but when i hover text image is not going down,may i know how to fix,check it here  http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/391/

Comment: @raazstret I would advise marking this question answered and then opening a new question, since this is a different issue. You have different elements moving, yet nothing that moves them together. You're all over the place there.

Comment: @raazstret You can do all this with CSS `:hover`: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Qf4Ka/392/